# Mount cifs on Ubuntu Operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I'm tryng to mount a shared folder from a Windows Server 2003 in a Ubuntu 18.04

Complete server information:

*VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

ID=ubuntu

ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"

VERSION_ID="18.04"*

My /etc/fstab is this:

```
//server/directory/source  /mnt/destination cifs vers=1.0,noperm,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,uid=0,gid=0,sec=ntlm,x-systemd.automount  0   0
```

but when I try to mount with command:

```
mount -a
```

I recive an error message:

> mount error(1): Operation not permitted Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

The file .smbcredentials is like this:

```
user=myusername
password=mypassword
domain=mydomain
```

Thank you for suggestions!

Comment: Is the Ubuntu a server or Desktop installation? If desktop can you access the SAMBA server via Nautilus (a.k.a. Files) > Other Locations?

Comment: VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"

Comment: Please [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1317738/edit) with the new information. Also add in your question, if it is a server or a desktop. In other words, does it have a GUI where you can point and click or do you have to type everything?

Comment: When mounting with `cifs`, try using `//WINDOWS.IP.ADDRESS.HERE/directory/source` instead of `//server/directory/source`

Comment: i tried using the IP but the error message is the same.

Comment: @user68186 I connect and edit all via ssh, I don't have a GUI, I have checked for typing errors several times.